# show multiple marker in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-markers

I have done till now to show multiple marker from server

```
    urlName = "http://bumba27.byethost16.com/infomagilandia/send_lat_lng.php";
$.post(urlName, function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( data );
    $noOfPlace   = obj.i;

    for($i=1;$i<=$noOfPlace;$i++)
        {
        $Lat = obj['lat' + $i];
        $Lng = obj['lng'+$i];

        newPlace = new google.maps.LatLng($Lat,$Lng);
        addNewMarker(newPlace)
        }

    });

    function addNewMarker(newPlace) {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newPlace,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        }));
    }
```

I have a database where 6 lat & lng is stored I need to show them on google map I have no problem to get the data from the server but when I try to put those data on google map as marker it is showing only 1st one(first lat & lng). can you tell me what is the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336600/every-infowindow-is-displaying-the-same-data-maps-api-v3/13625706#13625706

Comment: Are you sure that you loop iterates correctly ? Can you output `$noOfPlace`so we can make sure that it's not equal to 1.

Comment: yes `$noOfPlace` showing 7

Comment: @FawadGhafoor please update my code with that code but nothing is showing

`urlName = "http://bumba27.byethost16.com/infomagilandia/send_lat_lng.php";
 $.post(urlName, function(data) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( data );
  $noOfPlace   = obj.i;

  for($i=1;$i<=$noOfPlace;$i++)
   {
   var lat = obj['lat' + $i];
   var lng = obj['lng'+$i];
 
    var propPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    propMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: propPos,
     map: map
    });
   }
   
  });`